# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow "Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-manager

"Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow."

I've searched for answers and as many have suggested I restarted services, recycled pools and Workflow Manager, but here is the seemingly unique issue at my end.
Although **Service Bus** is installed according to the Web Platform Installer, the **Service Bus** AND **Service Gateway Services** are **NOT** listed under Services. It's as if they aren't installed.

**Workflow Server Status** - Workflow is Connected 
Both **Workflow Service Application** and **Workflow Service Application Proxy** are "Started".

**Snapshot of what I get when I try to run a SharePoint 2013 Approval**
[image: Snapshot of what I get when I try to run a SharePoint 2013 Approval]

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. Whew!
Go to Service Bus Configuration and reconfigure.
You will need your SQL Server Instance Name and initial phrase ( password ) from the original configuration.

Comment: can you please provide any link or steps to reconfigure the service bus?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Service Bus Message Broker was not working. Not sure what made it stopped but after starting it everything got normal. Thanks Mike for pointing to right direction.